# Java and Sybase

Tags: java, sybase

What is the difference between the drivers provided using jtds.jar and jconn3.jar?

Answer (score 5):

JTDS is open source (LGPL), the other is proprietary, made by sybase. In terms of which performs better, you would have to benchmark.

Sybase calls their latest JDBC jconn4.jar, so the version you are referencing complies with the JDBC 2.0 spec only. JTDS complies with JDBC 3.0. Whether or not that is important depends on the version of Java you are using to run your application.

Answer (score 1):

jTDS works with both Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase.  SQL Server is the product of a "collaboration" between Microsoft and Sybase, so that's not surprising.